# What algorithm to use for a graph problem?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:

There is a N*N randomly generated map, where there are treasures placed in random locations, and the character has to go grab one in as few turns as possible. Some of the sqaures of the map are normal terrain (take 1 turn to move through) while others are slow terrain (takes 3 turns to move through). The character spawns at a random location in the map, and can move vertically, horizontally and diagonally. Both the character, and a treasure occupy a single cell.

I initially did a BFS, treating the each cell in the map as a node, connected to each adjacent cell. The problem is sometimes the character tries to go to a treasure by crossing several slow terrain cells (beacuse it s the closest by distance) when in reality there was a faster path (a longer path, but faster to travel due to the slow/fast terrain mechanic).

On the other hand, if I use Dijkstra (weighting normal terrain as 1, and slow terrain as 3) all treasure locations must be checked (Dijkstra from character's position to Treasure1, Dijkstra from character's position to Treasure2, then treasure 3 etc) and considering the map is usually pretty big (n =~ 100), and there are hundreds of treasures, that feels really inefficent.

Is there a way to solve the BFS problem? If so, how?
If there isn't, anyone know a more efficient or better way to do it? (With Dijkstra or any other algorithm)

Comment: Dijkstra's *is* a BFS. So you can stop it as soon as a treasure is **explored**. The key concept is that nodes may be **visited** multiple times, but each node is only **explored** once. The first treasure to be **explored** is the closest treasure.

Comment: This is an algorithms question and not a C++ question.

Comment: "if I use Dijkstra..." -- nope, that part is wrong.  Use Dijkstra's algorithm and stop when you pull the first treasure off the queue.

Comment: Any example on how taht would look like? I ve tried to implement it but it s not working @MattTimmermans